# C# Ambiguous function overload - rectangle vs. rectanglef

Tags: c#, ambiguous

I have a line of code

```
System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush gradient = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(5, 5, 100, 100), Color.Red, Color.Green, 0);
```

That throws an error

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'LinearGradientBrush.LinearGradientBrush(RectangleF, Color, Color, LinearGradientMode)' and 'LinearGradientBrush.LinearGradientBrush(Rectangle, Color, Color, LinearGradientMode)'
```

Obviously that is correct since there's overload. How do I specify that I want to use Rectangle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is quite misleading here. The call is actually ambiguous between these 2 overloads:

```
public LinearGradientBrush(Rectangle rect, Color color1, Color color2, float angle);
public LinearGradientBrush(Rectangle rect, Color color1, Color color2, LinearGradientMode linearGradientMode);
```

The problem is that you're trying to pass the last parameter as `int` instead of `LinearGradientMode`. If you pass a value of `LinearGradientMode` enum it will compile:

```
gradient = new LinearGradientBrush(
                 new Rectangle(5, 5, 100, 100), 
                 Color.Red, 
                 Color.Green, 
                 LinearGradientMode.Horizontal);
```

**Edit**

Some explanation why the error message is so misleading in this case:

The process of overload resolution in C# is described in section 7.5.3 of C# language specification.

The first step is creating a set of applicable function members. Basically (ignoring `params` and optional parameters), these are all methods that have the same number of arguments as specified in the call, and there is an implicit conversion from each argument to the type of the corresponding parameter.

There are 4 applicable constructors `LinearGradientBrush` for the arguments passed:

```
public LinearGradientBrush(RectangleF rect, Color color1, Color color2, LinearGradientMode linearGradientMode);
public LinearGradientBrush(RectangleF rect, Color color1, Color color2, float angle);
public LinearGradientBrush(Rectangle rect, Color color1, Color color2, float angle);
public LinearGradientBrush(Rectangle rect, Color color1, Color color2, LinearGradientMode linearGradientMode);
```

because:

- There is an implicit conversion from `Rectangle` to `RectangleF` (1st argument)
- There is an implicit conversion from `int` to `float` (last argument)
- There is an implicit conversion from `0` to any `enum` type (last argument)

From this list, the compiler tries to find the best member to invoke. If it fails, it reports an error. The error message contains only signatures of 2 methods from the applicable members list.

If we wanted to sort these members using the rules described in section 7.5.3.2 we would get

```
1. public LinearGradientBrush(Rectangle, Color, Color, float);
1. public LinearGradientBrush(Rectangle, Color, Color, LinearGradientMode);
3. public LinearGradientBrush(RectangleF, Color, Color, float);
3. public LinearGradientBrush(RectangleF, Color, Color, LinearGradientMode);
```

The methods taking a `Rectangle` argument are better than the ones taking `RectangleF` argument because identity conversion is better than implicit conversion.

However, that's not what the compiler does. The compiler only looks for a single best member. If it cannot find it, it reports an error. The error message is based on the whole applicable member list and can contain any method signatures from that list.